# Function in R to determine complete cases

Tags: r, function, nested-loops

I have the following code to print the complete cases:

```
complete <- function(directory, id=1:332) {
data<-NULL
dat <- NULL
s <- NULL
   for (i in 1:length(id)) {
data[[i]]<- c(paste(directory, "/",formatC(id[i], width=3, flag=0),".csv",sep=""))   
df[[i]]<-c(read.csv(data[[i]])) 
s[i] <- sum(complete.cases(df[[i]]))
dat <- data.frame(cbind(id,nobs=s[i]))    
   } 
dat
}
```

The output that I get is as follows:

```
complete("specdata", c(2, 4, 8, 10, 12))
  id nobs  
1  2   96
2  4   96
3  8   96
4 10   96
5 12   96
```

The required output looks like this:

```
complete("specdata", c(2, 4, 8, 10, 12))
##   id nobs
## 1  2 1041
## 2  4  474
## 3  8  192
## 4 10  148
## 5 12   96
```

The .csv looks like this:

```
head(file)
        Date sulfate nitrate ID
1 2003-01-01      NA      NA  1
2 2003-01-02      NA      NA  1
3 2003-01-03      NA      NA  1
4 2003-01-04      NA      NA  1
5 2003-01-05      NA      NA  1
6 2003-01-06      NA      NA  1
```

As is evident from the 2 outputs the nobs value for all id's is the replicated corresponding to id==12. I'm unable to figure out a way to output the nobs corresponding to id. Lets ignore the ## in each line of the required output. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does an instance of your .csv files look like?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that. It looks like this:

Comment: You obviously misplaced the closing bracket of the for-loop. As it is now, it override `dat` in every iteration and makes this whole function basically pointless. If you place it before `dat <- data.frame(cbind(id,nobs=s[i]))` it might work.

Comment: I did that but still the same result.

Comment: Did you find a solution now?

Comment: Voted negative as this is a copy&paste from one of the coursera assignments of "programming in R", sad, really sad.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to clean your code:

```
complete <- function(directory, id) {
  s <- vector()
  for (i in 1:length(id)) {
      path <- c(paste(directory, "/",formatC(id[i], width=3, flag=0),".csv",sep=""))   
      data <- c(read.csv(path)) 
      s[i] <- sum(complete.cases(data))
  } 
  dat <- data.frame(cbind(id,nobs=s))   
  return(dat)
 }
```

If this does not work, you probably might want to check your functions `formatC` and `complete.cases`.

EDIT:

There were several redundancies in your code as well as two logical errors.
First, you dont need to initialize objects in R in order to give them a value. I deleted these two

```
data<-NULL
dat <- NULL
```

and changed the third into an empty vector. Second, you can see that I removed the indices of your `dat` and `data` objects and gave them a more expressive name. As these two objects are newly created in every iteration of the `for-loop`, it makes no sense to give them an index. Finally, you misplaced the closing bracket (as mentioned above) and created your `dat$nobs` from only one element of `s` (namely the last one):

```
dat <- data.frame(cbind(id,nobs=s[i]))
```

Fixing this into

```
dat <- data.frame(cbind(id,nobs=s))
```

did the trick.

Please consider reading a good beginners book on (R-)programming to gain a better understanding of control structures.

Comment: That works! But still need to understand where was the mistake in my code. Thanks.